Use data in Databricks delta lake as input to rule
I just starting with JBPM, and was wondering if this possible
In my use case data upon which business rules need to be applied is in Dtabricks delta lake and also in some cases MS SQL Server database.
So what needs to happen is when a workflow is triggered I would like to provide the from delta lake or sql server as input and the rule should evaluate each row and then enrich each row with particular classification based on the some criteria that is defined in rule
For example. Hypothetically If a data value of row is I classify it as Invoice, but if data value is O classify as Order
I just started with JBPM and have gone through tutorial but could not find an answer
